# How to map many-to-many with Code First to same class?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I use Code First with Entity Framework 5.

I have `User` class, where one user can be friends with many people.

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public Guid UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Friends { get; set; }
}
```

This however maps 0..1-to-many. How should I map many-to-many relationship with the same class in Code First?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add configuration class:

```
public class UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserConfiguration()
    {
        HasMany(u => u.Friends).WithMany();
    }
}
```

then, this needs to be added to context class

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserConfiguration());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Organization : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual Organization Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Organization> Children { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class OrganizationConfiguration : EntityMapperBase<Organization>
{
    public OrganizationConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(f => f.Id);
        Property(f => f.Name).HasMaxLength(20).IsRequired();
        HasMany(f => f.Children).WithOptional(f => f.Parent).Map(m => m.MapKey("ParentId")).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        HasMany(f => f.Users).WithRequired(f => f.Organization).Map(m => m.MapKey("OrganizationId"));
    }
}
```

may it help you

Answer (score -1):

You should have tow navigation properties

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public Guid UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> FriendsOfMine { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> FriendsWithMe { get; set; }
}
```